# Computing the inverse of a permutation

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

I didn't understand the permutation and of course, I got this question wrong.

> Compute the inverse of the following permutation:
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix} 
> 1&2&3&4&5&6\\
> 2&5&4&1&6&3
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

Could you please help me with this question and provide an explanation?

Furthermore, is it possible to compute the direct permutation, not the inverse one? If yes, how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean my "direct permutation"?

Comment: I suspect the real issue here is understanding the notation.

Comment: Turn it upside down and, if you like, rearrange the vertical pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permutation

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
2&5&4&1&6&3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

means that you have six objects, standing in a line, and the object in position 1 has moved to position 2, the object in position 2 has moved to position 5, and so on, up to the object in position 6 that has moved to position 3.

The *inverse permutation* is the permutation that moves the objects back where they started. The original permutation took the object that was in position 2 and  moved it to position 5, and the inverse permutation must move it back, so the inverse permutation  must move the object at position 5 back to position 2.

Can you do the rest?

Comment: If I didn't misunderstant, is this the answer?

Comment: $$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
2&5&4&1&6&3
\end{pmatrix}
$$ is not the answer.  It is the permutation that your question is asking for the inverse of.

Comment: Sorry, I try to add an image..But, it didn't work..

Comment: (5 4 1 2 3 6) Is this the answer?

Comment: If you mean $$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
5&4&1&2&3&6
\end{pmatrix}
$$ then no, that is not the answer.  The original permutation moves $2$ to $5$, so the inverse permutation should move $5$ to $2$. But your permutation moves $5$ to $3$. But if you really mean the permutation $(5\, 4\, 1\, 2\, 3\, 6)$ then no, that is not the answer, because it should move $5$ to $2$, but $(5\, 4\, 1\, 2\, 3\, 6)$ moves $5$ to $4$.

Comment: I mean the first one...

Comment: Sorry, I think I have cheated..I look at Wiki, and find the inverse is (4 1 6 3 2 5). Is this the answer?

Comment: If you mean $$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
4&1&6&3&2&5
\end{pmatrix}
$$ then yes, that is the answer.  $(4\,1\,6\,3\,2\,5)$ means something else, and is not the answer.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: Let $\pi$ be your permutation. You know that $\pi^{-1}$ satisfies the condition $\pi^{-1}\circ\pi=id$. Now, you know that $\pi(1)=2$, and you know that $$(\pi^{-1}\circ \pi)(1)=id(1)$$
Now, try to simplify this equation. What do you get?

Comment: Given $\pi^{-1}\circ\pi=id$, what is the meaning of $id$? Simply a permutation where each element maps to itself, i.e. $(123)$ is the identity of $S_{3}$?

Comment: @KevinMeredith $id$ is simply the identity element, the permutation that "does nothing." $(123)$ is not the identity, it maps $1$ to $2$, and $2$ to $3$ and $3$ to $1$. The identity contains no cycles, so it can be written as $()$.

Comment: And $id(1)$ = 1, per your answer? Or, more generally, $id(x)$ = x?

Comment: @KevinMeredith $id(x)=x$ for all $x$, yes. That is the permutation that maps each element to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Another Hint

\begin{pmatrix} 
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
2&5&4&1&6&3
\end{pmatrix}
reads "1" goes to "2", "2" goes to "5", ...

if you want to invert that permutation "do" the reverse.
\begin{pmatrix} 
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
 &1& & &2& 
\end{pmatrix}
because "2" goes to "1", "5" goes to "2", ..., the rest is for you :-)

And I believe you mean the cycle notation for the permutation, if you are talking of a direct permutation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understant why it is 1 below 2... 1 goes to 2, 2 goes to 5, 5 goes to 6, 6 goes to 3, 3 goes to 4, 4 goes to 1. Is it like this?